# Using READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT with EF code first 5

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, transactions, database-deadlocks

Recently, our users sometimes got **timeout expire error**, when they wants to update some record on DB.(I think something like deadlock occurs in DB) 
our DataBase is `SQL Server 2008 R2`, and our application developed by EF5 code first.

Today i read an article about using `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option in SQL Server, i think this option could help us to prevent deadlock in DB.
Occording that article, it has two steps:

1- Activating `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` in DB

```
ALTER DATABASE testDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
ALTER DATABASE testDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

2- Use `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` option in code:

```
using (var transactionScope =
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel= IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
{
  // update some tables using entity framework  
  context.SaveChanges();  
  transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

This sample, used `TransactionScop` statement. but we didn't use `TransactionScop` for managing `Transactions`. for example we have inheritance in our model, and when we call `.SaveChange()`, `EF` create and manage `Transaction` itself.

Is there any way to use `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`without using `TransactionScop` statement?

Comment: From my tests, if you set the _IsolationLevel.Snapshot_ in the TransactionOptions, it will override the database setting and the transaction will execute under _Snapshot_ isolation level, instead of _ReadCommittedSnapshot_

Answer (score 6):

`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` and `SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` are not the same thing.  Once you enable `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on the database all `READ COMMITTED` transactions will use it.

`SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is a completely different isolation level and needs to be called out in code like you are doing.

Further Reading:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can begin transaction without `TransactionScope`, for do this use the `Connection` property of `DbContext`:

```
public static DbTransaction BeginTransaction(this DbContext context, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
{
    if (context.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        context.Database.Connection.Open();
    return context.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
}
```